# Elapsed time in apex_workspace_activity_log table in Oracle apex

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex, apex

When I run this query select * from apex_workspace_activity_log;

I am getting different columns along with elapsed_time column which is giving value in decimals like
0.221954
0.020009.
How can I convert it into minutes/hours?

Answer (score 0):

I believe [numtodsinterval()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/NUMTODSINTERVAL.html) will be your friend here, depending on the exact output format you're chasing. If you're after specific values, you can use the EXTRACT expression

```
select elapsed_time
      ,NUMTODSINTERVAL(elapsed_time, 'second') iv
      ,extract(minute from NUMTODSINTERVAL(elapsed_time,'second')) mi
      ,extract(second from NUMTODSINTERVAL(elapsed_time,'second')) ss
from apex_workspace_activity_log l;
```

[image: example of results]